# Sorting vector of tuples not working in c++

Tags: c++

I have a vector of tuples which I want to sort first w.r.t. 1st value, then w.r.t. 2nd value.

Here is the code used:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool mysort(const tuple<int, int, int>& a, const tuple<int, int, int>& b) {
    if (get<0>(a) < get<0>(b)) {
        if (get<1>(a) > get<1>(b)) return false;
        else return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

int main() {
    vector<tuple<int, int, int>> queries;
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        int l, r, c;
        cin >> l >> r;

        queries.push_back(make_tuple(l, r, i));
    }
    sort(queries.begin(), queries.end(), mysort);

    // print sorted queries

    for (int i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++) {
        cout << get<0>(queries[i]) << ", " << get<1>(queries[i]) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input used:

```
6
1 2
1 5
1 3
2 8
3 3
5 8
```

Output from above code:

```
1, 2
1, 5
1, 3
2, 8
3, 3
5, 8
```

Expected sorted output is:

```
1, 2
1, 3
1, 5
2, 8
3, 3
5, 8
```

Issue reproducible link: https://ideone.com/4iVJuD

Comment: Recommended read: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

Comment: tuples already have a `operator<`

Comment: can you please clarify if one line missing from your output is just a typo here, or really the output you see?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Pls ignore `cout << "Printing range sorted queries" << endl;` printing. Point is to get the sorted output of ranges.

Comment: @user3243499 I didnt even notice that line, but your acual output is 5 entries, and expected is 6

Comment: btw why "please ignore" ? It is much simpler if you show the exact output

Comment: @idclev463035818 ok, updated the description, also provided the ideone link for the issue reproducibility.

Comment: @user3243499 so it was a typo, thats all I was wondering about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in `mysort` function. If the first element of the comparing tuples is equal, you just say the second tuple is less. Consider the following code:

```
bool mysort(const tuple<int, int, int>& a, const tuple<int, int, int>& b) {
    if (get<0>(a) < get<0>(b)) return true;
    if (get<0>(a) > get<0>(b)) return false;
    if (get<1>(a) < get<1>(b)) return true; // Here the first element is equal
    return false;
}
```

This would result in the expected output.